# old KDE project

Tags: ide, porting

So I have this old C++, KDE project for QT 3.3.x. The IDE's version is 3.0.0-10, the one that comes with Linux RedHat 7.3.

I'd want to get rid of the dependency to this environment, in other words I'd like to manage the project throught Makefiles. Alternatively, it would also be acceptable if I could port this KDE project to Eclipse.

Has someone been successful in doing this?

Comment: Would this question be better placed on SO?

Comment: Do I ask the question again on SO or is it administrators' job?

Comment: Moderators can migrate the question for you, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

This question is rather old but have been left unanswered...

The Qtish solution to this is to write a QMake project and from this generate Makefile. QMake is like CMake it is not really a build system but actually generates makefiles or visual studio projects or wherever is needed by the underlying build target.

The qmake documentation for Qt3 is [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/3.3/qmake-manual.html).

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I recommend porting the project to Qt 4. Start by creating a new project in Qt Creator and importing your source files. Replace references to Qt 3's classes with their equivalents in Qt's [Qt3Support](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt3support.html) module. If you do it that way, then you should be able to get the Qt 4 version working extremely quickly.